# Prevent HTTP Request Headers from trimming

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, http-headers, httprequest

I have a RESTFul Webservice that allows user to download files. The user will send a request with a couple of HTTP request headers to specify the files to download.

However, I discovered that the http request headers will get trimmed automatically, for example if the user send the header value - "a", with a space at the end, it will get trimmed and thus the value becomes "a". How can I prevent the values from being trimmed?

Below is my code is to retrieve each header value:

```
string filename = context.IncomingRequest.Headers["filename"];
```

`context` refers to `WebOperationContext` class

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just read the raw request and extract what you need?

```
Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
var input = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

per the rfc2616 [specification](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) ( HTTP 1.1 - page 31 )

> "leading or trailing LWS MAY be
>      removed without changing the semantics of the field value."

Unfortunately, I do not know of http software that does not do this. For example, see this comment -> [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2006-01/0246.html)